# Android - Using coordinates in an image

Tags: android

How to allocate coordinates on an image?

I know that we can use geolocation to get user's current location, but how to allocate specific coordinates on a specific spot on an image? (There are several spots to be allocated with coordinates, but one spot at a time, right? :D)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this library, it helps to set co-ordinates on image how we do in map tag in html.

[AndroidImageMap](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap)

Comment: I got several errors in the code.. public boolean onTouchEvent(@NotNull MotionEvent ev)  What does that @NotNull do??